# Align button with respect to background image in XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have a background image and I need to put buttons in it. I have tried auto layout as well by fixing it's height and width (The button text was not part of the background, has been added manually), but it is not working for all screen sizes. I want two buttons equidistant from line that can be seen(like in iPhone 4 inch screenshot, line is part of the background). How can I go about doing that? Are there any other tools which might be helpful? I am using swift

[image: Preview in iPhone 4 inch and 5.5 inch]

Comment: Have you tried using auto layout?

Comment: "Login using..." text looks great on different sizes. Use autolayout for those buttons and use that label for referencing element.

Comment: Yes I did set vertical, horizontal spacing but it wont be the same for all screen sizes. Also the height and width. How can I use size classes? Will it be of any help?

Comment: The text was the part of the background image. Even if I explicitly add the text I will have the same problem as the buttons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way to do this is to add a hidden view which has a background color of clear. Add a constraint for this which centers it horizontally and a constraint which positions its top where you want it.

Make the width of this transparent view the space you wish between buttons or leave it as 1 wide if you wish and use offsets in the constraints described below instead. Make the height 1 so it takes up no space.

For the buttons align the top of the buttons with the bottom of the transparent view. This places the buttons vertically.

Finally pin the trailing edge of button 1 to the leading edge of the transparent view and pin the leading edge of button 2 to the trailing edge of the transparent view. Set the offset for the pins to be the distance you want the buttons from center if you gave your transparent view no width.

On all screen sizes, the buttons will now be relative to the center.

If you want to have them equally space out, you can add transparent views to the left and right of the buttons and pin them together so they act like spacers. So superview->spacer->button->spacer->button->spacer->superview.

Using the spacer approach, select the 3 transparent views and add a constraint for equal width. You buttons will now be spread apart equally.

Comment: Seems like it would work. I am completely new. Can you please suggest links on pinning?

Comment: Check out the apple layout guide here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html. Takes a bit of getting used to, but once you know it you will find all your coding much easier.

Comment: Hey I have another problem, suppose I remove the text Login using social accounts. I use a view as yo said which is centrally aligned and keep the vertical spacing to the view say x. x would be all screen sizes but that's not the ideal case. Ideally as in the background image it should be different for different screen sizes. Thanks again

Comment: Use size classes to change the constraint offsets. This lets you scale things differently for iPhone versus iPad in both portrait and landscale. If you want per iPhone type sizing, best to set the size in code. You can Ctrl-Drag a constraint into the controller header and make it an IBOutlet. In the code you can then set the constraint based on whatever algorithm you wish. This is handy for all sorts of things: e.g. positioning based on screen size at run time, collapsing and expanding views etc. You can even animate the constraint changes.